# must have a selection of subfields. Did you mean \"createEvent { ... }\"?", [graphql]

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql, graphql-js, express-graphql

I am learning graphql so please have patience with me.

My app.js looks like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const graphqlHttp = require('express-graphql');
const { buildSchema } = require('graphql');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Event = require("./models/event");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/graphql', graphqlHttp({

    schema: buildSchema(`
        type Event{
            _id: ID!
            title: String!
            description: String!
            price: Float!
            date: String!
        }

        input EventInput{
            title: String!
            description: String!
            price: Float!
            date: String!
        }

        type RootQuery{
            events: [Event!]!
        }

        type RootMutation {
            createEvent(eventInput: EventInput): Event
        }

        schema {
            query: RootQuery
            mutation: RootMutation
        }
    `),
    rootValue: {
        events: () => {
            return events;
        },
        createEvent: args => {
            const event = new Event({
                title: args.eventInput.title,
                description: args.eventInput.description,
                price: +args.eventInput.price,
                date: new Date(args.eventInput.date)
            });
            return event
                .save()
                .then(result => {
                    console.log(result);
                    return {...result._doc};
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                    throw err;
                });            
        }        
    },
    graphiql: true
}));


mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${process.env.MONGO_USER}:${process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD}@localhost:27017/graphqldb`, {useNewUrlParser: true});

var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection errror:'));
db.once('open', function(){
    console.log('Connection open');
    app.listen(5000);
});
```

and my event.js looks like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const eventSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Event', eventSchema);
```

when I tried to very it, by accessing the URL: http://localhost:5000/graphql

```
mutation {
  createEvent(eventInput: {title: "title", description: "description", price: 9.99, date: "2019-05-15T08:04:26.461Z"})
}
```

I encounter an error related to subfields:

> {   "errors": [
>       {
>         "message": "Field \"createEvent\" of type \"Event\" must have a selection of subfields. Did you mean \"createEvent { ... }\"?",
>         "locations": [
>           {
>             "line": 3,
>             "column": 3
>           }

Please let me know what I am missing. As I understand my field does not contain any subfields.

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE:**

This is not a duplicate from the questions posted. As you can see in my mutation, I supplied all the required fields but still I recieved this error.

The error happened only when I tried to use mongoose but before it is working as expected.

Comment: Nope, I already checked, and as I have said, my fields does not have subfields.

Comment: This is not a duplicate from the questions posted. As you can see in my mutation, I supplied all the required fields but still I recieved this error.

The error happened only when I tried to use mongoose but before it is working as expected.

Comment: I'm sorry but yes, your mutation returns an object of type "Event" as you define in `createEvent(eventInput: EventInput): Event`. That error means you have to select some field of the type "Event" on when triggering your mutation like it is explained on the possible duplicate of. Just try to run the same mutation and selecting some field like `mutation { createEvent(...) { title } }`

Comment: Thank you that solved it. I am really new to this so I can't understand what you mean.